# Do not exit on clicking back button uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I am developing an app in uwp where I dont want to exit the application on back button click(on mobile).Instead of exiting I want to run it in background(it also uses a timer which triggers every 5 second).

Could anybody please help me on this.

Thanks..

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish every five seconds?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot-Want to set a wallpaper in every 5 seconds

Comment: Why would you need to set the wallpaper every five seconds? The user won't look at their wallpaper every five seconds.

Comment: Ok lets say If I set the wallpaper in every 5 hours..What I need to in that case

Comment: Also please refer to latest questions for my codes-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551853/extended-execution-in-uwp/44555288#44555288     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546208/background-task-in-uwp/44551529#44551529

Comment: Looking at your current questions and previous ones, you seem to have a confusion with the way the Background tasks work. I strongly recommed you to take a look at my answer and refer the links in it.

Comment: Thanks for helping..Just want to inform..when I post something here.I normally do lot of search,already seen those links before..None of really helped..this answer helped me lot and please read comments as well on that post..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44605481/setting-a-wallpaper-in-background-task/44605811?noredirect=1#comment76199786_44605811

Answer (score 0):

A few things to mention:

1. A UWP app does not exit on pressing back button. It generally goes into a `suspended` state. It starts running in background only if you have registered a `background task`.
2. A background task can be triggered using a `time trigger`. But the minimum time period between 2 triggers is **15 minutes**. So, you might want to look into some other to handle this.

You might want to look at these if you want to understand more clearly

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/04/28/the-lifecycle-of-a-uwp-app/

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/06/07/background-activity-with-the-single-process-model/