# Background task in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I want to use a background task for my UWP app.

The below code, is my back button click event in windows mobile:

```
private async void MainPage_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
       var access= await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
        var task = new BackgroundTaskBuilder
        {
            Name="My task",TaskEntryPoint=typeof(backGroundTask.Class1).ToString()
        };
        trigger = new ApplicationTrigger();
        task.SetTrigger(trigger);
        task.Register();
        //var result = await trigger.RequestAsync();
        if (Frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            Frame.GoBack();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }


public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        clearData();
        count1 = 0;
        getDownloadedSongs();

        dispatcherTimer1.Tick += DispatcherTimer1_Tick;
        dispatcherTimer1.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
        dispatcherTimer1.Start();
        _deferral.Complete();



    }
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer1 = new DispatcherTimer();

 private async void DispatcherTimer1_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {

        try
        {
              clearData();




        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }



    }
```

But this code is not working, when I click back button. As per expectation background task code should work, but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is happening because the application is getting closed before the background task is registered... it is not recommended to register background task on back requested or any other code that takes time. Try registering your background task on some other event before the user actually exists the application.

Comment: Thanks for replying..Now I am registering this on another button click event ..Still not working..I must be missing something

Comment: Did you declare the background task in the appx manifest? Is 'backgroundTask.Class1' a public activatable WinRT component? Also can you clarify what you really want to accomplish? I am wondering if ExtendedExectuion would be a better approach to your scenario.

Comment: Yes..I have already declared..Also tried extendedexecution...not working...I just want to try,when i click back button ,instead of suspending app I want to get all images from pictures library and set it as wallpaper

Comment: In short ..when I click back button(its a one page app),I want to minimize the app in windows mobile(Desktop it is working as expected)..

Comment: ExtendedExecution is the right path for this. What is not working with it? Also I think I found the bug in your background task code. I will post an answer and I suggest you ask a new question about ExtendedExecution.

Answer (score 0):

Your background task is exiting before the DispatcherTimer gets a chance to ever execute, because you mark the Deferral as complete. You should hold on to the Deferral until all the work in your background task has been completed (or until you receive a TaskCanceled event from the system).

Comment: Thanks for replying..I have not tested this yet..Tomorrow morning I will test it..As i Need both the ways..I posted another question for extended execution-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551853/extended-execution-in-uwp

Comment: Now I have commented out Defferal Complete...Still not working

Comment: Please be more specific. What does "not working" mean? Do you get an error? Does the task not trigger? Something else? If you can provide a repro project we can help you debug it.

Comment: Please share a complete repro project

Comment: Ok..Please give me sometime

Comment: HI..Here is the test app..Please keep some jpg images in your pictures library in windows mobile...What I need to achieve is-When you run the app ,in first page when you click back button...wallpapers should start setting as background wallpaper which should run in each 15 mins..https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgLAtkS5ABsAgqo36IVyQ3AeTbIWyw

Comment: Are you able to find the problem

Comment: I haven't been able to pinpoint the problem in your project yet (still looking, might be a typo somewhere or something) - but I have built a new project from scratch that shows it working: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AovTwKUMywTNl5wginhWm3KEFFQteg

Comment: Tested this test project..Still same problem..When I click back button,it executes,but when I stop debug button..Its not working

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The task will run every 15min. Run it without debugger, like your users. And wait 15 min for the task to get triggered.

Comment: Sorry for confusion...In my Run method I used my method(setbackgroundwallpaer)..That is not running...your toast method is working

Comment: If you have a problem/question with setting the wallpaper I suggest you start a new question for that and we close this one.

Comment: have created a new question-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44605481/setting-a-wallpaper-in-background-task