# Extended execution in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I want to use a background task for my UWP app.

The below code, is my back button click event in windows mobile-

```
private async void MainPage_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
   var access= await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
    var task = new BackgroundTaskBuilder
    {
        Name="My task",TaskEntryPoint=typeof(backGroundTask.Class1).ToString()
    };
    trigger = new ApplicationTrigger();
    task.SetTrigger(trigger);
    task.Register();
    //var result = await trigger.RequestAsync();
    if (Frame.CanGoBack)
    {
        Frame.GoBack();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}


public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    clearData();
    count1 = 0;
    getDownloadedSongs();

    dispatcherTimer1.Tick += DispatcherTimer1_Tick;
    dispatcherTimer1.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
    dispatcherTimer1.Start();
    _deferral.Complete();



}
DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer1 = new DispatcherTimer();

 private async void DispatcherTimer1_Tick(object sender, object e)
{

    try
    {
          clearData();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

what is the way to do it with Extended execution in uwp ..specifically for windows mobile 10

Answer (score 2):

ExtendedExecution will allow you to keep running and finish your task before you get suspended. Please take a look at the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ExtendedExecution) for ExtendedExecution

Comment: None of them working for my case..I have written ExtendedExecution codes  in App suspending event..But it is not working..

Comment: Is it possible to minimize the app in windows mobile when i click back button

Comment: What do you mean by "minimize"? On the phone the equivalent of minimize is putting the app on the navigation backstack, which should happen automatically for you when you click the back button.

Comment: Is your application crashing by any chance? Try with an empty app and press the back button. Do you not see it on the navigation backstack? (do a long-press on the phone's back button to view the backstack)

Answer (score 0):

Extended Execution has been in talks for quite a long now. You can definitely continue the app execution even when it is minimized. I don't have a working sample yet but you can get some insight by looking at the link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution)