# Setting a wallpaper in background task

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime, windows-10

I want to get all images from a storage folder in background task.
Firstly registered a background task in app_entering background method.
I am also able to debug Run method,but none of the await methods are working-

```
public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {

        var differal = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
         UpdateUI();
        differal.Complete();

    }

public async void UpdateUI()
    {

            StorageFolder folder = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFolderAsync("Wall_e_photos")//here execution stops and backgroundtaskhost exits.
            var files = await GetFilesAsync();
            foreach (StorageFile file in files)
            {
                if (file.Name.Contains("wall_e"))
                {
                    }

  }
       }
```

Struggling from long time..Initially background tasks was not working,after it started working..now storage folder issue (backgroundtask exits when getting the folder).

Also for a note I followed this link-
http://www.codeguru.com/win_mobile/win_store_apps/setting-wallpapers-in-a-windows-8-store-app-with-vb.htm

There they have used dispatcher,If I use var dispatcher=MyDispatcher = GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher,then It gives null reference exception

IF I use Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView ,then it gives could not create a new view exception..

Please help me...

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by "storage folder issue". Do you get an exception or something else?

Comment: If you want to answer please help..Please dont down vote..There is nothing wrong with question..Nothing happens on that line It just stops executing and does not proceed to next line..no exception nothing...in output windows backgroundhosts exits(already mentioned)

Comment: The question doesn't have enough info on the problem, so please update it so others know what you are facing. I don't see where you mention in the question that the background task exits without exception. Trying to help you articulate good questions, so you get good answers from the community.

Comment: Did you declare the "Picture Library" capability in your app's manifest?

Comment: Sorry, missed the comment in the code snippet. My bad! (edited the post and the vote now)

Comment: Yes I have declared Pictures library capability in app manifest..It just stops executing there,in that specific line..and Please note Background task project is WinRT project,I think this is kind of deadlock issue..May be threading issue on that line

Comment: This is not necessarily the only issue, but you're calling `differal.Complete()` too soon. Either change `UpdateUI` to `async Task` then wait on the task before calling `differal.Complete()` (or use a continuation), or pass the deferral as parameter to `UpdateUI` and call it at the end

Comment: Infact I tried with out differal.Complete() ,As per your Toast project..Still not working..Also Please tell me the replacement of Task in WinRT as Task cant be used directly in WinRT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue here:

```
var differal = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
UpdateUI();
differal.Complete();
```

`UpdateUI` is an async method, so the method call will end immediately (while the method continues executing in the background). Therefore, you're calling `differal.Complete();` before the end of the work.

A simple way to solve that is to pass the deferral as parameter to the `UpdateUI` method, and complete it at the end:

```
public async void UpdateUI(BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral)
{
    StorageFolder folder = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFolderAsync("Wall_e_photos")//here execution stops and backgroundtaskhost exits.    
    var files = await GetFilesAsync();
    foreach (StorageFile file in files)
    {
        if (file.Name.Contains("wall_e"))
        {
        }
    }

    deferral.Complete();
}
```

An alternative is to change `UpdateUI` to be `async Task`, then wait for its continuation:

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    var differal = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    await UpdateUI();
    differal.Complete();
}

public async Task UpdateUI()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying....In first method..If I  use deferral.Complete(); at the end of UpdateUI method..Will time trigger work..I mean Will it run again after 15 mins

Comment: Sorry..I asked because..Its not happening...After defferal.complete..its not calling backgroundtask

Comment: It will run again after approx. 15min if you have registered the TimeTrigger as recurring task: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.TimeTrigger

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for helping me...I will accept this as answer as this really helped me,though the actually solution for this was (atleast to me) adding this line before requestaccessasync-BackgroundExecutionManager.RemoveAccess()....Thanks again